# Why did NASA use Falcon Heavy rather than SLS to launch Europa Clipper?

Tags: cost, sls, super-heavy-lift-launch-vehicles, science-return

The SLS will only take about three years to get to Europa, the Falcon heavy will take 5. This means that there won’t be as much science return since the spacecraft is spending more of its operational lifetime floating in space. Should NASA have stuck with SLS for launching Europa Clipper?

Comment: You have a lot of questions already, but have not accepted any answers yet. Please reward the people who have helped you by [accepting answers to your questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hint: which one of the two has a 100% success rate?

Comment: Another hint: Which one costs \$97 million, and which one costs \$2.1 billion?

Comment: Which rocket has already flown and has been successful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several reasons:

- Falcon Heavy works, SLS will probably work in the future
- Falcon Heavy is cheaper, depending on the kind of calculation you do by an order of magnitude

But the main reason stated is "[forseen lack of SLS vehicles](https://spacenews.com/cost-growth-prompts-changes-to-europa-clipper-instruments/)" because SLS missions for the forseable future are dedicated to the [Artemis program](https://www.nasa.gov/specials/artemis/).

There is only one flight of SLS planned per year and the first 5 flights are already booked for Artemis. And that is only if there are no further delays. After those 5 flights we don't know how and if SLS will continue to fly.

Additionally: operational lifetime is limited by other factors than by "total time spent in space". [Europa Clipper](https://europa.nasa.gov/spacecraft/meet-europa-clipper/) has solar panels for its energy needs. So that's not a resource that will run out after some time. It will need some fuel for course corrections on its way to Jupiter, but the amount does not really depend on the time it takes to travel there.

The lifespan of the craft will probably be limited by the fuel available for attitude control and maneuvers to stay in the right orbit. Also, the radiation environment is harsh. **Very** harsh. This might also be a limiting factor for the lifetime. But a longer transit time to Jupiter should not influence that either.

So a launch on [Falcon Heavy](https://www.spacex.com/vehicles/falcon-heavy/) seems to be very benefical to the mission over all.

Comment: But wouldn’t there be some degradation of the panels over time due to radiation and dust particles hitting the craft at high speeds?

Comment: @A.NAsker yes, Photovoltaic cells do age. But this will probably not be a limiting factor for the lifetime of the craft. Also, the density of dust in interplanetary space is low enough that abrasion is not considered an issue. Micrometerites could an issue be and a longer travel time increases the risk of being hit by one. But the risk of such a hit damaging the spacecraft significantly is very low.

Answer (score 6):

It would have taken longer to wait for the SLS to be ready to launch. That is why they choose Falcon Heavy. Even though it will take 2 years longer, it will get there sooner than waiting for the SLS.

Comment: Well, that is just a possibility

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Congress has turned large parts of the space program into a jobs creation program and SLS has fallen victim to that. Nobody in Congress cares what flies, when it flies or even if it flies as long as the cash keeps flowing supporting high tech jobs in key states. Unsurprisingly SLS is not well suited to anything in particular and costs a ridiculous amount of money per launch.

Falcon heavy can lift lift 63.8 tonnes to LEO which is sufficient for most purposes. For those that require more Starship should be operational before SLS is retired and should be capable of lifting 150 tonnes to LEO.